# select id from table and distinct column y

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `exchange` WHERE `photo` = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 18
```

How can I only get distinct `location` values?

For example doing this but it returns an error:

```
SELECT `id`, distinct(`location`) FROM `exchange` WHERE `photo` = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 18
```

Example table:

```
id    location

1        7
2        8
3        4
4        4
5        2
6        32
```

Example result (when LIMIT 5):

6,5,4,2,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` works for the whole row, not for the value of each column. Remove the column `ID` and you will have unique location.

```
SELECT distinct `location`
FROM `exchange` 
WHERE `photo` = 1 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 18
```

**UPDATE 1**

You can use *AGGREGATE FUNCTION* like **MAX()** and grouped them by their `ID`. Try this again,

```
SELECT location, MAX(ID) ID
FROM exchange
GROUP BY location
```

Comment: I need to select the id to then create the member class

Comment: can you please add sample records and results? :D

Comment: results for what? and the table has about 30 columns

Comment: your desired result, don't include all column, just the essential part only.